# How do i loop a condition that checks if p element is empty?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling on trying to loop my code.
What i am trying to do is to check if p element is empty, if it is, then the variable "part number" will be inserted. If not, then repeatedly check all p element from machine 1 to 3, until an empty p element is found.

Code below just checks if p element is empty and replaces with a variable if it is.

More info is shown in the Flow Chart.
[Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acr6G.png)

```js
let paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working'));
paras.forEach((para,n) => {
    if (para.innerHTML === '') {
       para.innerHTML = partnumber;
    }
});
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working">
<p id="machine2" class="working">
<p id="machine3" class="working">
```

Comment: A `<p>`'s inner HTML will never be an empty string. It will always contain at least a newline character. (This might be browser-dependent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot break out of a `.forEach`, use a `for..of`:

```
for(const para of paras) {
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
     break;
  }
}
```